# From OLS to semi-parametric GAM: parametric vs no-parametric

Tags: generalized-additive-model, parameterization

I am quite new to this kind of topic, but for my master thesis i built an multiple linear regression with OLS. Now I want to control for non-linear relationships using a semi-parametric GAM. My Question is: What is the right way to decide which variables are parametric and which are non-parametric? I would've included a smooth funktion s() for every variable and the looking at the edf's and if they're equal to 1 this is a linear relationship and if they're higher, then i would've said there's a non-linear relationship. Is that the right procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an exploratory approach to guide your choice as to what (continuous/discrete) predictor variables should be allowed to have non-linear effects.

Simply construct component plus residual plots (also known as partial residual plots) for each of those variables after fitting your multiple linear regression model with OLS. If any of the component plus residual plots suggest nonlinearity, then you could model the corresponding effects as nonlinear in your GAM model.

R has a function called crPlots in the car package which helps construct component plus residual plots: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-0/topics/crPlots.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and plotted the  explainatory variable "age" against the log of the transaction price, because from my advisor i know that there has to be a non-linear relationship... but I don't know how to see that because of that plot. Maybe you could explain it a little bit for me :) The link to the plot is: https://picload.org/view/dlllcwcl/rplot01.jpg.html

Comment: Is the outcome variable in your model log(kaufpreis)? If the plot you linked to is the component plus residual plot for the explanatory variable age, then that plot doesn't show any evidence of nonlinearity of the effect of age. While the theory predicts a linear relationship between log(kaufpreis) and age controlling for the other explanatory variables in your model, your data do not seem to support that.

Comment: Ok, I get that point. But when I run the GAM with these variables the Output shows a nonlinear relationship. Or maybe I didn't understand it right :) It would be nice if you could take alook at the output and the graphs of the splines: https://picload.org/view/dlllwllw/output1.jpg.html and https://picload.org/view/dlllwlcr/splines.jpg.html .... Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Were your data collected over time? Also, can you share a plot of the estimated nonlinear effects?

Comment: It's pooled cross-section collected over time, transaction prices from different houses in different months, because of that the time dummies. Here are the plots: https://picload.org/view/dllidarl/nonlin.jpg.html